# jquery select custom attribute in child controls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table with class="cloneable" that has rows containing one control per row.  The controls may be textarea, checkbox, radio, or input[type=number].  Each control has a custom data-answersetid attribute. I would like to select all child controls under the .cloneable class and update each of the data-answersetid attributes to the value of a counter variable, lastanswersetid. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```js
let lastanswersetid: number = 0;
const me: any = $('.cloneable').last(); //there might be several cloneables so just get the last cloneable
$('*[answersetid]', me) ? .each(function(index, value) {
  console.log(index, value);
  console.log($(this));
  lastanswersetid++;
  $(this).prop('aswersetid', lastAnswersetid);
}); //set the data-answersetid to the last answerset value
```

```js
  <table id="questionTable" class="table @("Q33,Q65".Contains(Model.QuestionnaireAndChoices.First().QuestionKey) ? "cloneable" : "")">
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model.QuestionnaireAndChoices)
      {
        <tr id="@item.QuestionID"
            @("Q64".Contains(item.QuestionKey) ? "class=cloneable" : "Q70,Q71".Contains(item.QuestionKey) ? "class=notCloneable" : "")>
          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionKey)
          </td>
          <td class="question">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)
          </td>
          <td>
            @switch (item.ChoiceUIType)
            {
              case "UI-CHK":
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("Checkbox2", new { userID = Model.UserID, questionID = item.QuestionID, questionKey = item.QuestionKey, choiceList = item.Choices });
                break;

              case "UI-DROP1":
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("Dropdown2", new { userID = Model.UserID, questionID = item.QuestionID, questionKey = item.QuestionKey, choiceList = item.Choices });
                break;

              case "UI-RAD":
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("RadioButton2", new { userID = Model.UserID, questionID = item.QuestionID, questionKey = item.QuestionKey, choiceList = item.Choices, question = item.Question, radioGroupName = item.QuestionKey });
                break;

              case "UI-NUMBER":
                {
                  int thisLength = 10;
                  string thisUiWidth = "150px";
                  if (item.QuestionKey == "Q38")
                  {
                    thisLength = 3;
                  }
                  @await Component.InvokeAsync("Input", new { userID = Model.UserID, questionID = item.QuestionID, questionKey = item.QuestionKey, choiceList = item.Choices, inputLength = thisLength, uiWidth = thisUiWidth });
                  break;
                }

              case "UI-TXT":
                {
                  <div class="md-form amber-textarea active-amber-textarea">
                    <textarea name="@item.QuestionKey" id="@item.QuestionKey" class="md-textarea form-control persistable" rows="3"
                              data-questionid="@item.QuestionID" data-userid="@Model.UserID"
                              data-questionkey="@item.QuestionKey"
                              data-useranswerid="@item.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.UserAnswerID"
                              data-codesetid="@item.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.ChoiceID"
                              data-oldvalue="@item.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.OtherDescription"
                              data-answersetid="@item.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.AnswerSetID"
                              data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
                              title="@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.OtherDescription) ? string.Format("Answered by {0}", item.Choices.First().AnsweredBy) : "")">@item.Choices.FirstOrDefault()?.OtherDescription</textarea>
                  </div>
                  break;
                }
              default:
                {
                  @*just display the text*@
                  <div>Render raw text here</div>
                  break;
                }
            }
          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, it should be `[data-answersetid]`, also use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to set the value.

```
$('[data-answersetid]', me) ? .each(function(index, value) {
  console.log(index, value);
  console.log($(this));
  lastanswersetid++;
  $(this).data('answersetid', lastAnswersetid);
}); //set the data-answersetid to the last answerset value
```

If you need the actual attribute in the DOm updated you'd need to use [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(this).attr('data-answersetid', lastAnswersetid);
```